# How to reconfig Tkinter scrolled text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this situation where I need to make the scrolledText as readonly, so the user can only add values to it through a button, like the following:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext

startingWin = Tk()

myEntry = Entry(startingWin, font=("Courier",25, "bold"), width=15)    
myScrolledText = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(startingWin, font=("Courier",25, "bold"),width=15, height=3, state='disabled')

def addEntryContentToScrolledText(entry, scrolledText):
    entryValue = str((entry.get()).strip())
    scrolledtext.config(state='normal')
    if entryValue not in str(scrolledText.get('1.0', 'end-1c')) and entryValue != "":
        scrolledText.insert(INSERT, (entryValue + "\n"))
    scrolledtext.config(state='disabled')    

myAddButton = Button(startingWin, text="Add")
myAddButton.config(command=lambda: addEntryContentToScrolledText(myEntry, myScrolledText))

myScrolledText.grid(row=0, column=1)
myEntry.grid(row=0, column=0)
myAddButton.grid(row=1, column=0)
startingWin.mainloop()
```

However, I get this error `AttributeError: module 'tkinter.scrolledtext' has no attribute 'config'`

How can I reconfigure the scrolledText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your widget name is `myScrolledText`, not `scrolledtext`:  (scrolledtext is the imported module name)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext


startingWin = Tk()

myEntry = Entry(startingWin, font=("Courier",25, "bold"), width=15)    
myScrolledText = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(startingWin, font=("Courier",25, "bold"),width=15, height=3, state='disabled')

def addEntryContentToScrolledText(entry, textwidget):
    entryValue = str((entry.get()).strip())
    textwidget.configure(state='normal')
    if entryValue not in str(textwidget.get('1.0', 'end-1c')) and entryValue != "":
        textwidget.insert(INSERT, (entryValue + "\n"))
    textwidget.configure(state='disabled') 


myAddButton = Button(startingWin, text="Add", command=lambda: addEntryContentToScrolledText(myEntry, myScrolledText))

myScrolledText.grid(row=0, column=1)
myEntry.grid(row=0, column=0)
myAddButton.grid(row=1, column=0)
startingWin.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It appears that my problem was passing the argument with the same imported module name. Thanks for pointing this out.
But you made a small mistake in the above code. You used ´myScrolledText´ under function call. I think one should just change the passed argument name to somethin like ´st´ and then of course needs to change all ´scrolledText´ under the function to ´st´

Comment: Yes, good catch. I had not checked the arg name. it is fixed now. You are welcome.

Comment: If you rename the argument, you need to rename all occurrences. There's still `scrolledText` in the function twice instead of `myScrolledText`.

Comment: argh, thanks, good catch - I changed the arg name so that it doesn't shadow one from puter scope. @fhdrsdg Please let me know if you find something else. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah that's even better! After all, the main problem in the question was using names too similar to one another.